# Simulate a serial port that actually is an internet port

Tags: centos, serial-port

In CentOS, how do I make a fake USB serial port that is actually an internet port (like port 80 for http)?

Edit: 
I'm sorry that I didn't make it clear. I'm trying to make a server-side compiler and uploader for `Arduino` so that the user can program on any device (for example, an user can program on an unjailbroken iPhone and upload to `Arduino` board through bluetooth). Traditionally this is done locally and the uploader program `avrdude` uses USB to communicate with the `Arduino` board. I wish to put `avrdude` on server, somehow trick the program so that the talk through USB actually goes through internet and reaches the iPhone, and then iPhone uses bluetooth to talk to `Arduino`. I'm not sure if this is even possible, but I'd like to have a try.

Comment: So do you want USB port or a serial port? And what do you mean by "that is actually an internet port"? USB, serial and Internet are using completely different protocols and aren't compatible with each other. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: until you can provide more info, you can look at `socat`.

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't make myself clear. Please check the edit. @gronostaj

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't make myself clear. Please check the edit. @meuh

Comment: So you want to connect Arduino to the Internet through USB? You need a modem then.

Comment: @gronostaj No. I want to program Arduino with iPhone. `avrdude` cannot be put in an iOS app so it must be on the server, and since Arduino cannot by itself connect to the server iPhone is used as a middle man, connecting the server and arduino. I therefore have to wire the USB port which `avrdude` writes to onto an internet connection, so that data can go to my iPhone and then to Arduino. There will be no USB on any device except the virtual USB port on server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `socat` command to connect a pseudo-tty (which should be 
good enough for avrdude) to a socket. Eg:

```
socat PTY,link=$HOME/myserialline,raw,echo=0  TCP4:somehost:23
```

would open port 23 on *somehost* and transfer all read/writes done to 
pty `$HOME/myserialline` (which `socat` creates as a symbolic link to the pty in `/dev`).

You still need something on your iphone to listen on that port.